# Remove white spaces from properties in list of the objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list of object:

```
public class Location
{
    public string area { get; set; }
    public string sensorId { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

List<Location> items = List<Location>(){
new Location(){area = "london ", address ="king road", sensorId ="2134"},
new Location(){area = "moscow",  address ="george str", sensorId ="2134"},
new Location(){area = "york ",   address ="johnson str ", sensorId ="2134"},
new Location(){area = " tokyo",  address ="king road 5", sensorId ="2134"},
new Location(){area = "paris",   address ="elitom road", sensorId ="2134"}
}
```

how can I remove white spaces in area and address properties in items variable using linq?

Comment: Why should you use linq to do it?

Comment: Do you want to remove *all* spaces? Or just leading and trailing spaces? That is, should "king road" become "kingroad"? Or are you just trying to make " tokyo" into "tokyo"?

Answer (score 1):

IMO `Linq` should not be used for this but if you want, you can try this one :

```
items = items.Select(item => {
    item.area = Regex.Replace(item.area, @"\s+", ""); // remove all white spaces
    item.address = Regex.Replace(item.address, @"\s+", ""); // remove all white spaces
    return item; // return processed item...
}).ToList(); // return as a List
```

Comment: Why should you not use Linq for this?

Comment: @JimMischel You're not transforming the sequence into a new sequence, you're mutating the values in the sequence.  LINQ isn't designed to do that.  It's specifically designed to *not* do that.

Comment: @JimMischel Because a `for`/`foreach` loop would probably end up being more readable. Obviously it is opinionated though.

Comment: @JimMischel No, it's not.  It's creating a new sequence with exactly the same items in it, but mutating those items in the process of creating that new sequence.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I mis-read the code. I thought his code was similar to the other answer, which is not mutating the items.

Answer (score 0):

Partly done using lynq:

```
items = items.Select(x => new Location() { area = x.area.Trim(), address = x.address.Trim(), sensorId = x.sensorId }).ToList();
```

Comment: This only removes beginning and ending spaces, the OP wants to remove all whitespace

Comment: Also they don't want to remove whitespace from `sensorId`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder you're right for `sensorId`, but it was not clearly specified to remove all whitespaces -- according to the question I interpreted it as trim the required ones

Comment: @cramopy It said to remove whitespace.  Not whitespace at the start and end.  *That* is what you'd need to specifically specify if that were the desired behavior.